# how to get correct numbers of lines and categories

Tags: livecode

I have a stack on which there are 3 fields that toggle their colors and their corresponding checkboxes. At the same time the toggling should change the variable (gMyCategories) in order to calculate the correct number of lines and type of categories. The Select All button works OK, but the code for selecting and disselecting each category by toggling the text fields (Short, Medium, Long) does not work -  I don't get the correct line numbers and categories in the display fields: "categories" and "Will show".
The code is in the group "fldCat" (see the stack)

```
    global gAllLines,gMyCategories

on mouseUp
   set the itemDel to tab
   put empty into gMyCategories

   repeat with j = 1 to the number of fields of grp "fldCat"
      if the backgroundcolor of the target is white then
         set the hilite of btn (the short name of the target) of grp "CheckCat" to "true"
         put the short name of the target & tab after gMyCategories
         set  the backgroundcolor of the target to yellow
      else
         set  the backgroundcolor of the target to white
         set the hilite of btn (the short name of the target) of grp "CheckCat" to "false"
      end if
   end repeat

   delete char -1 of gMyCategories  --tab
   put gMyCategories into fld "SelCat"

   local LinesInMyCategories
   repeat for each line i in gAllLines
      if item 3 of i is among the items of gMyCategories then put item 1 of i &tab& item 2 of i & tab & item 3 of i &tab& item 4 of i &cr after LinesInMyCategories  --lines in selected categories
   end repeat
   delete char -1 of LinesInMyCategories  --return

   put the number of lines in LinesInMyCategories into fld "NrOfLines"
   put the number of items in gMyCategories into fld "NrOfCategories"
end mouseUp
```

What do I have to correct?
see the stack here:
[toggle field selection.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99863601/toggle%20field%20selection.zip)

keram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this modified code a try;

```
global gAllLines,gMyCategories


on mouseUp
   set the itemDel to tab
   put empty into gMyCategories

   # toggle the clicked field
   if the backColor of the target = white then
      set the backColor of the target to yellow
   else
      set the backColor of the target to white
   end if

   # build list of selected
   repeat with j = 1 to the number of fields of grp "fldCat"
      put the short name of field j of grp "fldCat" into tName
      if the backgroundcolor of field j of grp "fldCat" is white then
         set the hilite of btn tName of grp "CheckCat" to false
      else
         put tName & tab after gMyCategories
         set the hilite of btn tName of grp "CheckCat" to true
      end if

   end repeat

   delete char -1 of gMyCategories  --tab
   put gMyCategories into fld "SelCat"


   local LinesInMyCategories
   repeat for each line i in gAllLines
      if item 3 of i is among the items of gMyCategories then put item 1 of i &tab& item 2 of i & tab & item 3 of i &tab& item 4 of i &cr after LinesInMyCategories  --lines in selected categories
   end repeat
   delete char -1 of LinesInMyCategories  --return

   put the number of lines in LinesInMyCategories into fld "NrOfLines"
   put the number of items in gMyCategories into fld "NrOfCategories"
end mouseUp
```